# How to get what module/class is consuming heavy RAM using Visual studio 17 diagnostic tool

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, ram, diagnostics

I have to optimize RAM usage of a winform (.net 4.6) software.

This software on it's peak is taking huge amount of RAM (upto 1.5 GBs), and I'm not much familiar with most of it's modules. So I've decided to run a Diagnostic tool on it first to get general overview.

[image]

by this snapshots, I could have got couple of spots which is consuming big amount of RAM.

But that doesn't seem to be enough.

If you notice, snapshot number 10 and 11, It does provide me detail of around 650 MBs of Heap. But if you notice total process memory at that time was almost 1 GB.

I'm getting a clear detail of 650 MBs, from where I can get detail remaining RAM usage.

Any chances of it being occupied by Stack memory ? if so, from where i can get detail regarding that too?

Any other way to achieve same motive ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use other instrument (like dotMemory, it has a free trial). It will show you types of objects which consume memory.

Remaining RAM usage can be taken by stack, maybe unmanaged recourses, probably you have Large Objects in a Heap which can influence results.

Comment: I'll try this out and get back here.! Thanks